# Mysql How to check and change the value of MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes variable of NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, storage, clustered-index

When I am trying to create a table using NDB storage engine I get the following error:

```
"Got error 904 'Out of fragment records (increase MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes)' from NDB"
```

How to change the size of this variable?  I can't figure out where this is stored or set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a configuration option set in MySQL's config.ini file.

Comment: Well, I did not get any such option in my Config.ini file.
is there any other file which mysql read on startup.....

Comment: If it's anywhere, it should be in the [NDBD] section of the config. If it's not specified there, try adding it (change the number to whatever you wish):

MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=1024

Comment: Do i need to restart the ndb and mysql data nodes